# jquery implemetation issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery-1.10.1.min.js

I am trying to have a roll over cursor change (from pointer to grab) and a border color on selected for a radio image.   Here is the jquery in the  area:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Grid").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("cursor", "grab");
        }, function(){
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    });
});



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#List").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("cursor", "grab");
        }, function(){
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    });
});
</script>
```

My HTML is :

```
<div>
        <form>

                <span style="float:right; margin:-10px 100px 0px 20px;">Change view:&nbsp;</span>
                <span style="float:right; margin:-10px -200px 0px 0px;">
                    <input class="listing" id="List" style="visibility: hidden;" name="listing" onclick="hideForm()" type="radio">
                    <label class="listing" for="List"> 
                    <img src="/devsite/images/icons/row.png" alt="List" title=" List " border="0"></label>


                    <input class="listing" id="Grid" style="visibility: hidden;" name="listing" onclick="hideForm()" type="radio">
                    <label class="listing" for="Grid">
                    <img src="/devsite/images/icons/table.png" alt="Grid" title=" Grid " border="0"> </label>
                </span>
        </form>
</div>
```

the css is simple :

```
.listing img:hover {
cursor:grab;
border: 4px dashed #bbc3d3;
}
```

The hide form basically displays either a grid or list view of products.  The hideform works fine, I just can not get the roll over cursor change or the selected radio to have a border...

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jquery?

Comment: Why are you using `click` events for a mouse `rollover`? Use `hover()`. https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @Chrillewoodz jquery-1.10.1 isn't that old

Comment: I was using hover as well, sorry, was trying something else when I copied it over....

Comment: Works just fine now with hover: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/95nc5z1p/

Comment: I am just adding a feature to an existing website, I do not want to upgrade all of the jquery that is in place.

Comment: check console for errors, nothing wrong in the code shown

Comment: nothing wrong with 1.10. @Chrillewoodz is likely not aware that 2.xx series drops support for older browsers and both branches are active

Comment: it does not change the cursor on the web page I copied this code directly from it and it does not work....

Comment: are ID's being duplicated in page?

Comment: check the cosolel meaning look in firefox developer tools?

Comment: Or Chrome F12 console

Comment: id is only used on these elements.

Comment: well we need a way to replicate problem. As shown in above fiddle code itself should work. Check for any `!important` in css that would not allow changing cursor inline

Comment: All !important are placed on colors only, nothing on the cursor defines in the css.    I could show the page link if that would help...

Comment: Would a link to the page help?

Comment: http://www.kvmgalore.com/devsite/group.php?group_id=108

Comment: Which part of the page has the hover?

Comment: the two image found in the filter bar, grid or list views -- change views

Comment: Not seeing elements with `id="Grid"` or `id="List"` in that page. Can you be very specific?

Comment: The code I posted initially for the Grid / List view is an exact copy of what is presented on the web page, the id is contained in the <input > tag

Comment: Used the same for the label for the radio buttons....

Comment: Any luck seeing the issue?  I am really pulling my hair out at this point....

Comment: Anyone have a solution?